# Eclipse stops responding when changing to DDMS perspective

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, ddms

What could be causing the problem that Eclipse stops responding right when I try to change to DDMS perspective when debugging my Android application. Moreover, when I start the emulator it will try to attach the debugger forever without succeeding.

Edit:

I repeated the problem and there was nothing written in the log file. The latest logs were these lines:

> !ENTRY org.eclipse.libra.facet 4 0 2012-01-17 07:56:48.916
> !MESSAGE startup class must implement org.eclipse.ui.IStartup
>
> !ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 1 2012-01-17 09:00:40.308
> !MESSAGE NLS unused message: CodeAssistPreferencePage_showStub in: org.eclipse.php.internal.ui.PHPUIMessages

The time stamps doesn't match the time I repeated the problem though. But instead there was this pop up window:

[image]

Hopefully that helps a bit to debug this behavior.

-zaplec

Comment: Please post the last lines from the log file from .metadata folder inside your workspace

Comment: Added some more information about the problem.

Comment: Looks like you have PHP plugin/ PHPEclipse installed. I would recommend to try it with a eclipse version for java and without any plugin (except ADT). See if that fixes it.

Comment: Which version of Java are u using? (Number and 32/64 bit)

Comment: I right have the same issue with indigo!

Comment: I have 64-bit Java 1.7. I'll try to uninstall the PHP plugin.

Comment: Removing the PHP plugin didn't help. I've checked the configurations for the emulator as well and they are they should be.

Comment: I have the same problem.  The standalone versions of 'tools/ddms' and 'tools/monitor' also lock up for me, so I suspect this has absolutely nothing to do with Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. The problem was that AVD hanged somewhere at 27% and then I couldn't do really anything with Eclipse. The problem is somewhere in the AVD and re-installing the AVD didn't help me.

Instead this seems to work every time:

- Start virtual device from Eclipse's Window -> AVD menu
- Then right click the project and "Debug as -> Android Application"

Here you never need to close the virtual device and it's also a lot faster to use it this way.

Comment: Actually you never have to close the virtual device, it is an independent program running. You can kill eclipse and restart it, and it will still find any running virtual devices and show it on DDMS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: delete the AVD that is giving you the problem, then create a new one afresh and run/debug your application on it. I have just experienced the same problem, and recreating the AVD solved the issue for me.

Comment: I see the same problem, to the extent that I've given up using the DDMS or logcat output in Eclipse, but I use real devices and re-creating these is a lot more problematic...

I work around the issue by just running "adb logcat" in a terminal window and using grep, etc, etc to filter it's output, but I fondly remember some of the useful features of logcat and DDMS in Eclipse...